# gridview will display all record even though textbox is empty when searched

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, gridview

I have a textbox and a button that search. Once I type something in the textbox and clicked searched, the gridview will display all the records. The problem is if I enter nothing in the textbox and click search, it will give me all the records. I want it to give me record not found if nothing is enter in the textbox when search.

```
  protected void SearchBlog(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);

        try
        {
            string invalid = txtSearch.Text;

            String SQL = null;

            if (invalid == "all")
            {
                SQL = "SELECT BlogID, AdminNumber, Name, Description FROM [EntryTable]";
            }
            else
            {
                SQL = "SELECT BlogID, AdminNumber, Name, Description FROM [EntryTable] WHERE AdminNumber LIKE @searchAdminNumber OR BlogType LIKE @searchBlogType OR Name LIKE @searchName";
            }


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchBlogType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchBlogType"].Value = txtSearch.Text + "%";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchName"].Value = txtSearch.Text + "%";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchAdminNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchAdminNumber"].Value = txtSearch.Text + "%";

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            grdResult.DataSource = dt;
            grdResult.DataBind();
            lblError.Text = "";


            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lblError.Text = null;
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Record not found";
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error!";
            //lblOrderError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }



    private void bindResultGridView()
    {
        String ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);

        try
        {
            string invalid = txtSearch.Text;

            String SQL = null;

            if (invalid == "all")
            {
                SQL = "SELECT BlogID, AdminNumber, Name, Description FROM [EntryTable]";
            }
            else
            {
                SQL = "SELECT BlogID, AdminNumber, Name, Description FROM [EntryTable] WHERE AdminNumber LIKE @searchAdminNumber OR BlogType LIKE @searchBlogType OR Name LIKE @searchName";
            }


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchBlogType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchBlogType"].Value = txtSearch.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchName"].Value = txtSearch.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchAdminNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchAdminNumber"].Value = txtSearch.Text;



            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            grdResult.DataSource = dt;
            grdResult.DataBind();
            lblError.Text = "";

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error:" + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

protected void grdResult_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    int newPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grdResult.PageIndex = newPageIndex;
    bindResultGridView();
}
```

Edited this works

```
protected void SearchBlog(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BlogConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);

        try
        {
            string invalid = txtSearch.Text;

            String SQL = null;

            if (invalid == "")
            {
                SQL = "SELECT * FROM [EntryTable] WHERE BlogID=-1";
            }
            else if (invalid == "all")
            {
                SQL = "SELECT BlogID, AdminNumber, Name, Description FROM [EntryTable]";
            }
            else
            {
                SQL = "SELECT BlogID, AdminNumber, Name, Description FROM [EntryTable] WHERE AdminNumber LIKE @searchAdminNumber OR BlogType LIKE @searchBlogType OR Name LIKE @searchName";
            }


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
            con.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchBlogType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchBlogType"].Value = txtSearch.Text + "%";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchName"].Value = txtSearch.Text + "%";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchAdminNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters["@searchAdminNumber"].Value = txtSearch.Text + "%";

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(reader);
            grdResult.DataSource = dt;
            grdResult.DataBind();
            lblError.Text = "";


            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lblError.Text = null;
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "Record not found";
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error!";
            //lblOrderError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if I am mis-interpreting your question, but y not just add a IF statement if the search field is empty and save yourslef a round trip to the DB. Other wise, I believe that you are receiving all the records because of the 'OR' statements. Look at those.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
string searchString = txtSearch.Text;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
{
    // your search logic here
}
else
{
    // inform user of invalid search string / do nothing / whatever
}
```

If it's not valid to search on an empty string, it's probably better simply *not to search* if one is provided.

Comment: Can;t figure out how to do it using your method. I updated my post. Can u post that as a answer so i can tick it?. @Baldrick

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are hitting the database unnecessarily, even if the textbox is empty.

You should check first if the textbox is not empty. If it is empty or null, let the user know that the search field is empty OR You can use RequiredField validator on the textbox so that when they click the Search button without any data in the text, the user will be notified with a error message saying, box cannot be empty.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtSearch" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqName" controltovalidate="txtSearch" errormessage="Field cannot be empty!" />
```

Hope this helps !!